# how to show rss feed url in UIWebView in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to display url in `UIWebView` but I can not display, `webview` just call the fail with error method. My url is this "http://www.tekniknoktamarket.com/index.php?route=feed/google_base",

**So please help me how to display this url in `UIWebView`** **?**

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a `UIWebView` download and display the content from a URL, you need to go through a couple of layers of abstraction, the first being an instance of `NSURL`, which contains your URL string. Then, you hand the `NSURL` to an instance of `NSURLRequest`. Finally, you hand the `NSURLRequest` to the webView. It all looks something like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.your-url.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[yourWebView loadRequest:request];
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code loading a URL into a webview:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.theurl.com"]]];
```

If you're using this code and are encountering any problems, please provide the code you were using and the exact error